# Google play services missing in extra folder

Tags: android, google-maps, sdk, google-play-services

![SDK Extra Folder][1]

I can only see Android Support library in the Extra Folder of the SDK...

Previously this solution worked for me but now it didn't turned up,don't know why?

"Open SDK Manager>Tools>Manage-add-ons sites>User Defined Sites>New

In New, copy the given links one by one and you'll get it.

link 1->http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

link 2->https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated the Android SDK Tools to 23.0.2 and even updated the ADT plugin then the above links worked for me, previously it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Ended up with the solution of downloading the SDK again([download link](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe)) and copying the extra folder in the old SDK folder(or you can use new SDK also by changing the path in the eclipse).